# How to remove highly differentiated element from a list of numbers

Tags: python

I have some lists where each list contains similar numbers (tolerance: +/-10%). But sometimes the list also contains noises: elements with large differences from the other 'normal' elements.

Here are some samples:

```
a = [100, 102, 99, 225, 105]
b = [150, 142, 24, 153, 147, 315, 149]
c = [34, 33, 31, 80, 32, 30]
```

What I want is a simple way to automatically remove these noises. From the first list, the `225` should be removed. From the second list, the `24` and `315` should be removed. From the last list, the `80` should be removed. Currently, my code is this:

```
import math

def foo(numbers):
    numbers_filtered = []
    for i, n in enumerate(numbers):
        n_upper = n + (n * 0.1)
        n_lower = n - (n * 0.1)
        similar = 0
        for j, m in enumerate(numbers):
            if i == j:
                continue
            if m >= n_lower and m <= n_upper:
                similar += 1
        if similar >= math.ceil(len(numbers) / 2.0):
            numbers_filtered.append(n)

    print('%s -> %s' % (numbers, numbers_filtered))

a = [100, 102, 99, 225, 105]
b = [150, 142, 24, 153, 147, 315, 149]
c = [34, 33, 31, 80, 32, 30]
foo(a)
foo(b)
foo(c)
```

But I'm not satisfied with the code since I'm expecting much simpler code. Could you suggest me the easier way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Have you considered using `numpy`? It would be overkill if you just wanted to do this, but if you want to do more statistical stuff to data then there's no point reinventing several wheels.

Comment: Personally speaking I would do this by calculating the standard deviation of the list, and then removing all the elements n standard deviations from the mean.

Comment: I don't think I can use numpy. Actually the elements aren't numbers, but the properties of custom objects instead.

Comment: Looks like you're keeping the number if >half elements are withing +/-10% range. Shoud the simplified code maintain that property or you just looking for simple way to recude the noise (possibly suggesting different approach) ?

Comment: I just want to remove the noises, the logic can be different from my code. Yes, different approach is okay.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier; this lists several methods for outlier detection.

Comment: jayanth: thanks for the link.

Comment: Note that the +/- 10% comparison can be done with
`if abs(m-n) <= 0.1*n:`

Answer (score 1):

One of the simple approaches would be to use standard deviation:

```
avg = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
diff = [ (i - avg) ** 2 for i in numbers]
stddev = math.sqrt(sum(diff) / len(numbers))

# filter out outliers
result = []
for n in numbers:
    distance = abs(n - avg)
    if distance < stddev * FACTOR:
        result.append( n )
```

Defining correct `FACTOR` might be a challenge so that not too many numbers are dropped out. You might add additional outer loop to check how many numbers have been dropped and update the `FACTOR` accordingly. That would allow for logic like "keep at least 50% numbers".

Answer (score 0):

I know no python, but here is the concept. I'll take the array you used:

> `a = [100, 102, 99, 225, 105]`

And do it in one go over the array this way:

1. 100, 102 - diff 2 (2/100=.02 i.e. 2%), both ok
2. 102, 99 - diff 3 (3/102=.03 i.e. 3%), 99 is ok
3. 99, 225 - diff 126 (126/99=1.27 i.e. 127%), too high, drop it
4. 99 again, 105 - diff 6 (6/99=.06 i.e. 6%), 105 is ok

Comment: what about a list where the numbers are increasing in small amounts, but after some point the difference from the first element is no longer tolerable.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik that scenario would not fit the OP's case of removing higly different numbers. It's not really noise if it's steadily increasing. But this would fail if the two first values was noisy values.

Comment: well, that's the problem really: detecting outliers is quite a challenge and depends on a lot of factors. it's much better to use some standard establish method based on the situation.

Comment: @M4rtini Slight changes can be traced with alpha-beta filter (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_beta_filter#Sample_Program), where big error values will denote outliers

Answer (score 0):

Code for my comment:
This keeps only elements within a certain number of standard deviations from the mean.

```
>>> def mean(array, function=None):
        function = function or (lambda x: x)
        return sum(map(function, array))/len(array)

>>> def standard_deviation(array, function=None):
        function = function or (lambda x: x)
        array_mean = mean(array, function=function)
        differences = [(i-array_mean)**2 for i in array]
        return math.sqrt(mean(differences))

>>> def foo(array, function=None):
        function = function or (lambda x: x)
        deviation = standard_deviation(array, function=function)
        array_mean = mean(array, function=function)
        return [i for i in array if abs(function(i)-array_mean) <= deviation*TOLERANCE]

>>> foo([100, 102, 99, 225, 105])
[100, 102, 99, 105]
>>> foo([150, 142, 24, 153, 147, 315, 149])
[150, 142, 153, 147, 149]
>>> foo([34, 33, 31, 80, 32, 30])
[34, 33, 31, 32, 30]
```

Set tolerance to whatever value you want. For the results you wanted, I used 1.5.

This will also work if the elements are "attributes of custom objects instead". You can do this:

```
>>> foo(my_array, lambda x: x.some_attribute_we_want_to_compare)
```

or even better:

```
>>> from operator import attrgetter
>>> foo(my_array, attrgetter("some_attribute_we_want_to_compare")
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved by accessing list elements pairwise. I have written following code and verified the output is matching your expectation:

```
a = [100, 102, 99, 225, 105]
comp = -1
for x, y in zip(a,a[1:]):
    if comp != -1:
        x=comp
    if x-y > 10 or x-y < -10:
        a.remove(y)
        comp = x
    else:
        comp = x
print a
```

Output:

```
[100, 102, 99, 105]
[150, 142, 153, 147, 149]
[34, 33, 31, 32, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing to the median works for your examples but may be problematic if there is *lots* of noise - tweaking the tolerance may help in that case.

```
a = [100, 102, 99, 225, 105]
b = [150, 142, 24, 153, 147, 315, 149]
c = [34, 33, 31, 80, 32, 30]

tolerance = 0.1

for example in (a, b, c):
    example.sort()
    median = float(example[len(example) / 2])
    print example, median, 
    print [n for n in example if 1 - tolerance <= median / n <= 1 + tolerance]

>>> 
[99, 100, 102, 105, 225] 102 [99, 100, 102, 105]
[24, 142, 147, 149, 150, 153, 315] 149 [142, 147, 149, 150, 153]
[30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 80] 33 [30, 31, 32, 33, 34]
>>>
```